# Identify these trees in the USA?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, identification-questions

I have a question about my Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange post: [Identify these trees in the USA?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/63754/identify-these-trees-in-the-usa)

##### How ought [Identify these trees in the USA?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/63754) to be "more focused"? Do I need to post a new question for each tree in the pic?

[Jurp](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/20056/jurp) unwarrantedly claimed that

> [This looks like a school assignment. I vote to close.](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/63754/identify-these-trees-in-the-usa#comment83172_63754)

This is NOT a school assignment. This picture is mine. I am not in school. What on earth kind of school assignment would ask a question like mine???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the commenter could have phrased it more friendly, we *do* get “solve my homework” questions that occasionally look similar, although the photo quality is usually bette, and the closure is justified.

Yes, we expect [one question per plant you want to identify.](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/826/7456) We also expect that we can actually see sufficient details for an identification and your photo is very blurry, which means even if you narrow the scope down to one, I see no leaves, stems, bark… that would allow our community to give you precise answers except perhaps a rough guesstimate for the palms.

For identification questions, there’s a quite extensive [guidance on what details should be included](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/how-to-ask-plant-identification-questions) in the question to make sure that it’s answerable correctly and with precision. You should have been shown a specific screen when you used the “identification” tag, a mechanism we implemented to help new users.